# add a folding part to IDE

Tags: c, ide, clion

Can I add an extra folding part to my code? like as it does for if, for, etc. just dol the part I want to. (look at the picture) is there any shortcut to do this or any extra extensions?
I'm using Clion. but if you know this for any other IDEs I like to hear that.
thanks in advance

[this is an example of what I meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeQLj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This applies specifically to CLion.*

## A shortcut

You're going to want to select the code in question, and press `Ctrl + Alt + T` (on Windows at least). That shows a drop-down menu. One of the options available is *<editor-fold...> Comments*. Select that, and you're good to go.

## Manual input

Another approach is to add the markers yourself. Say you want to add foldability to:

```c
int i = 0, j = 0;
char c;
```

Then you can just add:

```c
//<editor-fold desc="Description">
int i = 0, j = 0;
char c;
//</editor-fold>
```

The `desc` attribute is optionnal but pretty cool, it displays your description when the code is folded.
More info on [JetBrain's website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding)

Comment: @alip While you're discovering your IDE, try out the `Ctrl + Alt + L` command after clicking your cusor to any position inside a file. It will format your code nicely (and you may get addicted).

It's opinionated and I'm not aware of how to change the formatting details, but they share my tastes and they seem to work from best practices, so I use it liberally.